# How to get notifications of Firestore Database changes & request a get call for only the changed documents (added or updated)

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

So far I am able to add a snapshotlistener to the collection:

```
db.collection("products/country/class/grade1/test").order(by: "qId").addSnapshotListener { [self] (querySnapshot, error) in
            
            //Handle Error:
            if let error = error {
                
                print("Error getting documents: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                
            } else {
                
                //No Documents Found:
                guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                    return
                }
                
                documents.compactMap { doc in
                    
                    let value = doc.data()
                    print (value)

               }
           }
}
```

However, I would like it where a little badge appears showing that there were databases changes & when the user presses the update button it loads only the changed (added or updated) documents

Comment: You're question asks about Firebase but is tagged Realm. And then.. what is the actual question? What part of your code does not work as expected? Please review the following two guides on asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Jay Thank you for pointing that out, changed to the proper tag now. The question is how do I get notifications a documents has changed on Cloud Firestore & only download the changed documents when the user presses the download button instead of automatic syncing from a real time listener

Comment: add merge true where you setting the data in firestore setData([yourData],merge:true)
secondly you are not getting the changes in right way

Comment: Thank you. How would you recommend getting changes the right way? Especially when something is deleted from the database? @ZeeshanAhmed

Comment: Part of the power of Firestore is it automatically notifies the app of changes in the underlying data. Perhaps reviewing the Getting Started Guide [Get realtime updates](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) would help clarify that feature *"Then, each time the contents change, another call updates the document snapshot"* What you're asking is covered in that guide; see [View changes between snapshots](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots) because that notifies the app of added, changed and removed events.

Answer (score 1):

```
class ChannelsViewController: UITableViewController { 
      private var channelReference: CollectionReference {
        return database.collection("channels")
      }
      private var channels: [Channel] = []
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

      channelListener = channelReference.addSnapshotListener { [weak self] 
      querySnapshot, error in
      guard let self = self else { return }
      guard let snapshot = querySnapshot else {
        print("Error listening for channel updates: \. 
     (error?.localizedDescription ?? "No error")")
        return
       }

      snapshot.documentChanges.forEach { change in
        self.handleDocumentChange(change)
        }
      }
   }
      
   private func addChannelToTable(_ channel: Channel) {
       if channels.contains(channel) {
         return
        }

       channels.append(channel)
       channels.sort()

       guard let index = channels.firstIndex(of: channel) else {
         return
        }
        tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
     }

   private func updateChannelInTable(_ channel: Channel) {
      guard let index = channels.firstIndex(of: channel) else {
       return
      }

    channels[index] = channel
    tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
    }

   private func removeChannelFromTable(_ channel: Channel) {
      guard let index = channels.firstIndex(of: channel) else {
        return
      }

     channels.remove(at: index)
     tableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
    }

  private func handleDocumentChange(_ change: DocumentChange) {
      guard let channel = Channel(document: change.document) else {
       return
     }

    switch change.type {
    case .added:
      addChannelToTable(channel)
    case .modified:
      updateChannelInTable(channel)
    case .removed:
      removeChannelFromTable(channel)
    }
  }


}
```

this is an example automatically update the tableView when add,update and delete on collection name "channel"
and the Channel as:

```
import FirebaseFirestore

struct Channel {
  let id: String?
  let name: String

  init(name: String) {
    id = nil
    self.name = name
  }

  init?(document: QueryDocumentSnapshot) {
    let data = document.data()

    guard let name = data["name"] as? String else {
      return nil
    }

    id = document.documentID
    self.name = name
  }
}

// MARK: - DatabaseRepresentation
extension Channel: DatabaseRepresentation {
  var representation: [String: Any] {
    var rep = ["name": name]

    if let id = id {
      rep["id"] = id
    }

    return rep
  }
}

// MARK: - Comparable
extension Channel: Comparable {
  static func == (lhs: Channel, rhs: Channel) -> Bool {
    return lhs.id == rhs.id
  }

  static func < (lhs: Channel, rhs: Channel) -> Bool {
    return lhs.name < rhs.name
  }
}
```